# Applescript: How to simulate multiple key press on MacOS

Tags: applescript

I know that applescript code like

```
key code 45 using command down
```

would use to simulate key press `cmd`+`n`.

But I hope to simulate the key press `Esc`+`fn`, while above syntax didn't work at all.

Comment: The `fn` key doesn't send a key event, there is no key code

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that I have to find another way to reach my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The escape and function keys both have AppleScript keycodes.

[List of AppleScript keycodes](http://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes/)

Function is 63, and escape is 53.

The following AppleScript would fire off Fn + Esc:

```
tell application "System Events"
   key code 63
   key code 53
end tell
```

Comment: I'm surprised this actually works